# Does any cubic polynomial become reducible through composition with some quadratic?

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, computational-number-theory

What I mean to ask is this:

given an irreducible **cubic** polynomial $P(X)\in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ is there always a **quadratic** $Q(X)\in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ such that $P(Q)$ is reducible (as a polynomial, and then necessarily the product of 2 irreducible cubic polynomials)?

I did quite some testing and always found a $Q$ that does the job. For example:

$P=aX^3+b,\quad Q=-abX^2,\quad P(Q)=-b(a^2bX^3-1)(a^2bX^3+1)$

$P=aX^3-x+1,\quad Q=-aX^2+X,\quad P(Q)=-(a^2X^3-2aX^2+X-1)(a^2X^3-aX^2+1)$

and a particular hard one to find:

$P=2X^3+X^2-X+4,\quad Q=-8X^2+5X+1,\quad P(Q)=(16X^3-18X^2+X+3)(64X^3-48X^2-11x-2)$

Could there be a formula for $Q$ that works for all cases?

It feels to me that this may have a really basic Galois theoretic proof or explanation, but I can't figure it out.

**Update.**  Maybe a general formula for $Q$ is close. For $P=aX^3+cX+d$ taking $Q=-adX^2+cX$ works.

Comment: Sorry, but why can't it be a product of an irreducible quadratic and an irreducible quartic?

Comment: @mathworker21: Then $P(Q)$ would have a quadratic root $\alpha$ and therefore $P$ would have a quadratic root $Q(\alpha)$, contradicting the irreducibility of $P$ (which means that a root would generate a field of degree $3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$).

Comment: For Unix+Maxima users: echo "factor(subst(-a\*d\*x^2+c\*x, x, a\*x^3+c\*x+d));" | maxima --very-quiet

Comment: There are a number of interesting results known about "composition factorization" of polynomials. I realize this is not what you're asking, but one could ask "which cubic polynomials $f$ and $g$ have the property that $f\cdot g$ has a composition factorization. In any case, here are two reference that you might find useful: 
Beardon, A. F. Ng, T. W. On Ritt's factorization of polynomials. J. London Math. Soc. (2) 62 (2000), no. 1, 127–138. [MR1771856]
Beardon, A. F. Composition factors of polynomials.  Complex Variables Theory Appl. 43 (2001), no. 3-4, 225–239. [MR1820924]

Comment: The case $P=aX^3+cX+d$ can be transformed through variable changes and rescalings, into the case $P=aX^3+bX^2+d$, giving then $Q=-(81a^3d+6ab^3)X^2-3b^2X-b/(3a)$. While I believe that there are always particular solutions over $\mathbb{Z}$, it's possible that general solutions can only be found over $\mathbb{Q}$...

Comment: Over $\mathbb{Q}$, for $P = ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ you get $Q = \frac{-27da^2 + 9bca - 2b^3}{27a}x^2 + \frac{3ca - b^2}{3a}x - \frac{b}{3a}$ by eliminating the $x^2$ term and applying your formula.

Comment: @Aurel - thank you. I asked the question over $\mathbb{Z}$, but between a possibly extremely messy integer solution and the neat rational one that you took the patience to work out, the latter is sort of more appealing. I tried to think of some way the existence of a rational $Q$ could be used in turn to prove the existence of an integral $Q$ (and bypass Schinzel's paper) but I don't see how.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You should refer to Lemma 10 (page-233) in [this](https://eudml.org/doc/204826)   paper by Schinzel where he proves that for any polynomial $F(x)$ of degree $d$  we have a polynomial $G(x)$ of degree $d-1$ such that their composition is reducible.

Comment: To save others the scrolling: Lemma 10 is on page 233 of the paper.

Comment: @AlexB. Indeed... I wish I saw your comment earlier!

Comment: Sorry @Yaakov Baruch I should have added page number. I will add right now.

Comment: The integrality of coefficients is achieved there by a suitable choice of some $k$; I'm not sure, but it seems to me that $k$ could be a chosen to be a rational function of the coefficients (maybe a very messy one, using sums of squares of many things to avoid using the max function), in which case the resulting $H$ (our $Q$) would be given by one formula in the coefficients.

Comment: @Hhhhhhhhhhh
You may compactify the scrolling altogether by choosing the syntax
http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa13/aa13113.pdf#page=29
$\;\ddot\smile$

Comment: See also [my paper with Bober, Fretwell, and Wooley](https://secure.math.ubc.ca/~gerg/papers/downloads/SVP.pdf), Theorem 3.2, to see that there are infinitely many such quadratic polynomials $G(x)$. (The method is certainly based on that of Schinzel.) For those with a background in abstract algebra, I believe our proof has more intuition behind it.

Comment: @GregMartin: Great, interesting article! Thank you.